# Error installing Chrome driver (selenium) dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, selenium-chromedriver

I need to install the Chrome driver - Selenium, I'm following the commands in this file: https://gist.github.com/ziadoz/3e8ab7e944d02fe872c3454d17af31a5

Configuration:

SO - Ubuntu 16

Python 3.4

But I'm not making progress

> sudo apt-get -f install -y unzip openjdk-8-jre-headless xvfb libxi6
> libgconf-2-4

output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libxi6 is already the newest version (2:1.7.6-1).
libxi6 set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgconf-2-4 : Depends: gconf2-common (= 3.2.6-3ubuntu6) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: gconf-service but it is not going to be installed
 openjdk-8-jre-headless : Depends: ca-certificates-java but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: java-common (>= 0.28) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libcups2 but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: liblcms2-2 (>= 2.2+git20110628) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libnss3 (>= 2:3.17.1) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libpcsclite1 (>= 1.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
 perl : Depends: libperl5.22 (= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.9) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6 is to be installed
 xvfb : Depends: xserver-common (>= 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.12) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libxfont1 (>= 1:1.4.2) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: x11-xkb-utils but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

how can I solve?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve with the commands:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get autoremove
```